# Duplicate Windows Handle of a local process

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

**Use Case**

I have a 64 bit server process which through IPC (COM+ RPC) gains access to the PID of a 32 bit Client Process. The Server Process Creates a new Window with a parent Window Handler. I need to display the New Window inside the Client's Window instead of a standalone popup on top of the Desktop Window.

**Process Adopted**

In order to Display the New Window on the parent Window, I first tried to

1. Get the Handle to the Top Window
2. Duplicate the Window Handle using DuplicateHandle
3. Create the new Window with the new Duplicate Window Handle

**Code**

In Order to Duplicate the Window Handle I adopted the following Code. Note this is not the actual code, but for brevity changed the non relevant parts. Also Note, the SetPriviledge Function was adopted from [Enabling and Disabling Privileges in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
bool Duplicate(HWND hWnd)
    {
    HANDLE pToken = NULL;
    HANDLE hProcess = NULL;
    HANDLE hDuplicateHandle = NULL;
    DWORD pid = 0;
    bool bReturn = true;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
    if(!(hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid)))
        {
        std::cout<<"Cannot Open Process:"<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
        bReturn = false;
        }
    if(bReturn && !OpenProcessToken( 
        hProcess, 
        TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, 
        &pToken ))
        {
        std::cout<<"Cannot Open Token:"<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
        bReturn = false;
        }
    //The SetPriviledge function was adopted from
    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619(v=vs.85).aspx
    if (bReturn && !SetPrivilege(
        pToken, 
        SE_DEBUG_NAME, 
        true ))
        {
        std::cout<<"Error Setting Priveledge:error"<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
        bReturn = false;
        }
    if(bReturn && !DuplicateHandle(
        hProcess,
        hWnd,
        GetCurrentProcess(),
        &hDuplicateHandle,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
        {
        std::cout<<"Error Duplicating Handle: "<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Source Handle is "<<hWnd<<" And the Duplicate Handle is "<<hDuplicateHandle<<std::endl;
        bReturn = false;
        }
    if (hProcess)
        {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
    return bReturn;
    }
```

**O/P From the Above Code**

```
Error Duplicating Handle: 6
Source Handle is 00150C1C And the Duplicate Handle is 00000000
Press any key to continue . . .
```

i.e. The Code fails with Error Code 6: ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

**Goal**

To Make the above code work so that I can Duplicate a Remote Windows handle of a Local Process. Alternatively, determine if the above is the correct process.

Comment: [`DuplicateHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms724251\(v=vs.85\).aspx) can't duplicate window handles. Window handles are global, so you should be able to use it directly from your application (as long as the other process cooperates).

Comment: `as long as the other process cooperates` : Please Explain

Comment: It can be tricky to get right, Raymond Chen (of Old New Thing fame) has a couple of articles about it e.g. [1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx) and [2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/31/10147981.aspx)

Comment: Isn't it easier to inject a dll in the target process, and have this DLL create the child window? You probably don't want to just create a window, but also have some logic to paint it and interact with the user.

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan: `Isn't it easier to inject a dll in the target process`, well nope not in this case. The Server and the Client runs on different bitness. Added this info in the Question. Thanks for highlighting

Comment: This is not ever going to go anywhere.

Comment: `This is not ever going to go anywhere` .... I didn;t get the Humor :-)

Comment: "Cooperate" the way an OLE container cooperates with OLE server. You are basically trying to reinvent [OLE in-place activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683898.aspx)